# Given a .gif, return the color components as X11-style hexadecimal specifiers (or equivalents)

Tags: image-manipulation, netpbm

I am a fan of `potrace`, and I recently read the [Potrace FAQ](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/faq.html).

The FAQ includes this beautiful one-liner:

```
cat img.gif | giftopnm | ppmcolormask #641b1b | potrace
```

The command I am looking for would return the codes of all the colors to be parsed by `ppmcolormask`. It could return, according to `man ppmcolormask`:

```
   You can specify color five ways:

   o      An X11-style color name (e.g.  black).

   o      An  X11-style  hexadecimal specifier: rgb:r/g/b, where r g and b
          are each 1- to 4-digit hexadecimal numbers.

   o      An X11-style decimal specifier: rgbi:r/g/b, where r g and b  are
          floating point numbers between 0 and 1.

   o      For  backwards  compatibility, an old-X11-style hexadecimal num‐
          ber: #rgb, #rrggbb, #rrrgggbbb, or #rrrrggggbbbb.

   o      For backwards compatibility, a triplet of numbers  separated  by
          commas:  r,g,b,  where  r  g  and  b  are floating point numbers
          between 0 and 1.  (This style was added before MIT came up  with
          the similar rgbi style.)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat foo.gif | giftopnm | ppmhist -noheader -hexcolors | awk '{ print "rgb:"$1"/"$2"/"$3 }'
```

will give you a list of all the colors in X11 rgb:r/g/b format.